# How to deploy custom DataCacheStoreProvider for write-through and read-behind on Azure

Tags: azure, appfabric, azure-appfabric, appfabric-cache

Is it possible to deploy custom DataCacheStoreProviders on Azure?  I'm currently trying to deploy and test one locally, but I'm not sure how to go about this because the documentation doesn't cover my scenario.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it not possible.
You can find all supported features here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278350.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is specific to cloud Service, isn't it?

I don't have exact experience on how to get all of that working however during one similar discussion the outcome was that you can use DataCacheStoreProviders with Azure if after building and register DataCacheStoreProviders in your machine, you can access them using Windows Azure Cache modules i.e. using DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName) and process cache items. IF you try and met any problem in any step I can find some ways to help you after you post your issue.

Comment: Yeah, it's specific to the Caching Preview for azure, not the Azure caching service.